# What mistake have I made in this code(C++)?

Tags: c++

I was solving a problem on codechef:
https://www.codechef.com/NITWMA01/problems/QPALIN.It required to input m number of input cases after getting the value of m from the user. I always used to run a loop of: 
while(m--)
{//input test cases}, but in this problem I don't know why the loop is running less than m times when I have to get input cases m times. I tried running the code with the sample input(with m having 6) but main() returned 0 after getting just 4 inputs(and printint respective outputs wherever necessary).
My code is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int n,m,op,x,l,r,i,j,xorpair=0;
   char k,s[100000];
   scanf("%d",&n);
   scanf("%s",s);
   scanf("%d",&m);
   for(j=0;j<m;j++)
   {
     scanf("%d",&op);
     if(op==1)
     {
       scanf("%d",&x);
       scanf("%c",&k);
       s[x-1]=k;
     }
     else
     {
      xorpair=0;
      scanf("%d%d",&l,&r);
      for(i=l-1;i<r;i++)
      {
        xorpair^=s[i]-'0';
      }
        if(xorpair==0)
        {
            printf("YES\n");
        }
        else printf("NO\n");
     }

   }
    return 0;
}
```

PS: I have replaced cin with scanf. Also I believe I was not able to properly convey what problem actually I am facing. So here's the test case that explains it more clearly:

(What it should be like)
Sample input:
7
abbacca
6
2 1 4
1 1 z
2 1 4
1 4 z
2 1 4
2 5 7

Sample output:
YES
NO
YES
YES

**Following is the problem that I am facing:**
When I run the program for the above input, this is what appears on the output screen

**7

abbacca

6

2 1 4

YES

1 1 z

2 1 4

NO

1 4 z**

**Process returned 0 (0x0)**

I am not able to enter inputs 6 times and after 4th input it returns 0.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to mix C I/O (`scanf` etc) with C++ I/O (`cin >>` etc).

Comment: The first mistake is that you don't use whitespace. The second one is that you use `scanf()` and `istream::operator>>` which are equally unreliable.

Comment: Your nickname seems to be program. Debug your code please.

Comment: @Paul R Sir,I have made corrections and added some more details. Can you please address my problem.

Comment: Since I never use scanf myself, I might be as bad at predicting its behavior as the OP.  But experience with scanf long ago plus reading many posts online tells me scanf is usually the problem in a simple program like this.  Debugging with a debugger is generally better than throwing in some extra printfs.  But not in this case.  The easy way to diagnose a scanf problem is add a printf after each scanf that might in any way be questionable and display the result of that scanf.  In this case, the bug is then obvious.

Comment: I didn't get a good look at the `cin` version of the program before it was changed to `scanf`.  Typically `cin` is easier to get right than `scanf` but the post implies the same bug was in the `cin` version.  The assumption that the loop isn't working was still leading you away from correct diagnosis.  I'm sure the loop was always correct and the input not working.

Comment: I can't help you it seems. Walking you through how to debug your code is getting me downvoted so I'll walk away. It seems SO is not be the best place for you to get the help you need to debug this code. Best of luck.

Comment: @jwpfox Thank you very much,Sir. I appreciate your efforts. :)

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%c"` does not do what you seem to expect.  It reads just the `' '` before the char you want.  Then the next tries at reading `op` and `x` fail leaving `op` still equal to 1, so you do two of operation 1 for every once that you intended to.

Comment: Thank you very much,Sir. I didn't have clue for so long of what mistake I was making even after going through lot of content online. And this silly mistake drove me crazy. Feeling very relieved now after finding the error. Thanks once again. :)